# How to use later version of es that is later to es2015 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript

Haii I am New to visual Studio , i have created a simple Type Script file Test.ts Here is the code

```
let hm:Map<number,String> = new Map<number,String>();
let uname=1;
let pass="String";
hm.set(uname,pass);
console.log(hm);
```

i am compiled the file using
**tsc Test.ts**

but i am getting following error could some one help me how to resolve , i am not using angular just a type script file thats it

```
Test.ts:1:8 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

1 let hm:Map<number,String> = new Map<number,String>();
```

how to resolve this error , do i need to use tsconfig.json necessarily or i can change the Editor to use later version of es2015 directly

Comment: It's pretty clear, have you tried `changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later`?

Comment: Hey i am new to vs code , where can i find 'lib' compiler option, do i need to create tsconfig.json file??

Answer (score 1):

In the tsconfig.json, try adding the target library as below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

Comment: bro do i need to create tsconfig.json file for every project , bcz in typescript website  i saw tsconfig file will be created in root of every project, but mine is a single ts file, i didnt get any tsconfig.json file

Comment: @Sri Yes, you can generate a tsconfig file with `tsc --init`

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial usually the typescript takes default compiler options based on your typescript compiler, but if some es2015 or later method may not support, so when you getting the error you can set your target ts version

Comment: Haii I Created tsconfig.json file and tried to build it but i am getting the error

Comment: Executing task: tsc -p c:\Users\Admin\Test\tsconfig.json <

tsc : File C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ tsc -p c:\Users\Admin\Test\tsconfig.json
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Answer (score 0):

[If you invoke tsc with a filename it ignores tsconfig.json. It should work if you just execute tsc without any CLI arguments.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29523#issuecomment-456395207)

So I

1. created the **tsconfig.json** file by calling `tsc --init`;
2. uncommented the `"lib": []` property;
3. added `"es2015"` to the lib array: `"lib": ["es2015"]`;
4. typed `tsc` in the command line;
5. killed bugs;
6. repeated action 4

and that helped: I got the **file.js** script that could be executed by `node file.js`!